# Puppet Master install

Tags: puppet, redhat

I am using below release of redhat

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
```

I am trying to install puppet master on this server.

Here is what I did:

```
rpm --quiet -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/x86_64//puppetlabs-release-6-10.noarch.rpm
 yum install puppet-master
Setting up Install Process
No package puppet-master available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I guess I need different package than what I have, Could someone point me to right direction here.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the `puppetlabs-release` package install successfully? Did you fetch all yum repositories afterwards?

Comment: Yes it is installed successfully

**yum install puppet** worked, 

**puppet -V
3.6.2**

But I want to install puppet-master on this node.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have a typo in the URL you used.

```
rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/x86_64/puppetlabs-release-6-10.noarch.rpm
yum install -y puppet-server puppet facter
```

Comment: You mean the doubled slash? That is not an issue.

Comment: is puppet-server is puppet-master? I remember installing it as 

**yum install puppet-master**

then how do I install puppet-agent?

Is it been changed?

Comment: Ah, indeed. According to the [docs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/install_el.html#step-3-install-puppet-on-the-puppet-master-server) `puppet-server` **is** the correct package name on RHEL like systems. (It should be `puppetmaster` on Debian-likes). - I stand by my comment about the URL though. That should be fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

The package is **puppet-server** not puppet-master

```
sudo yum install puppet-server
```

Comment: [Puppet Master Install](http://www.slashroot.in/puppet-tutorial-installing-puppet-master-and-puppet-agent), this blog says **the package "puppet-server" contains the puppet master server** do you think this is wrong??

Comment: Yes,that Anonymous [comment](http://www.slashroot.in/comment/789#comment-789) is wrong. There is no [puppet-master](http://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=puppet-master&submit=Search+...) rpm available.